# Packing a bootloader as kernel image

Tags: linux, kernel, boot-loader

Can a bootloader (let's say lilo) be packed as a valid zImage to trick other bootloaders to chainload another bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody needs the answer just in case, I found an acceptable(for me) approach. You just let the normal Unix/linux kernel to boot then you just kexec into grub or another bootloader. Maybe this could be scripted as an init script.